# Elegantly selecting subsets by a property

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My database has *tasks*, which have *assignments* that relate *employees* to tasks (among other things). Users make *entries*, which always have a task. I found a bug in the entry creation code that prevented employees being automatically added to the assignments list; I want to write a migration that will create assignments for every employee who put an entry against a task and doesn't have one.

This is my current approach:

```
Task.all.each { |task|
            assigned_employees = task.assignments.map(&:employee)
            task.entries.select{ |entry| assigned_employees.exclude?(entry.employee) }.map(&:employee).uniq.each { |orphan_employee| 
                task.assignments.create(employee: orphan_employee, task: task)
            }
        }
```

The select-to-map-to-uniq is ugly. Can I do this more elegantly?

Worth noting: entry.employee is a delegate that goes through another class.

Edit: I figured I'd come back and address this; a senior programmer rewrote this call to use joins and pluck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A senior programmer rewrote this query as follows:

```
Task.find_each do |task|
  assigned_employees = task.task_assignments.map(&:employee_id)
  orphans = Timesheet.joins(:timesheet_entries).
    where(timesheet_entries: { id: task.timesheet_entry_ids }).
    where.not(timesheets: { employee_id: assigned_employees }).
    pluck(:employee_id).uniq

  puts "Found #{orphans.size} missing TaskAssignments for Task##{task.id}." if orphans.any?

  orphans.each do |orphan_employee_id|
    task.task_assignments.create(employee_id: orphan_employee_id, task: task)
  end
end
```

Worth noting:

- find_each is much more appropriate for this query than all.each, as it'll run this query in batches at a time and keep the system performant.
- orphans is now being assigned to, which allows us to provide feedback in the logs when we run the migration
- using where instead of select keeps our query slimmer
- we can use the much more succinct `pluck` instead of the clunky `map(&:employee)`